# Assembly in instruction math syntax

Tags: assembly, x86

In assembly there are often instructions like:

```
mov eax, [ebp+4]
mov eax, [ebx + ecx*4]
```

My question is: What can I do in this brakets?
Can I add and multiply all registers and immediates or are there limits?
Can I use division and subtraction too?
I searched for it with google, but I couldn't find any good reference.

Comment: See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86#Addressing_modes in addition to the answers to see what registers apply. You'll want to look at the 32 bits modes (to start with, at least)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The general format for an address operand in 32-bit and 64-bit modes is:

```
[reg1 + reg2*mult + ofs]
```

`mult` must be one of 1,2,4,8. `ofs` is an immediate value, i.e. a constant numeric value. It can be positive or negative.

Not all three parts have to be specified, so for example `[eax]` or `[ecx*2 + 5]` are valid.

Normally, the `eip`/`rip` register cannot be used as one of the register values. But in 64-bit mode there is a special "RIP-relative addressing" mode, which can be specified as `[rip + ofs]`.

Comment: I'd like to add that the immediate value must be a numeric literal, so you must specify it as a number when you type the instruction.

Comment: @MicroVirus That's what "immediate" means in this context. I've clarified it.

Comment: @interjay is ofs 8, 16 or 32 bit?

Comment: @kaetzacoatl It can be up to 32 bits.

Answer (score 1):

```
Instruction Prefix                0 oder 1 Byte
Address-Size Prefix               0 oder 1 Byte
Operand-Size Prefix               0 oder 1 Byte
Segment Prefix                    0 oder 1 Byte
Opcode                            1 oder 2 Byte
Mod R/M                           0 oder 1 Byte
SIB, Scale Index Base (386+)      0 oder 1 Byte
Displacement                      0, 1, 2 oder 4 Byte (4 nur 386+)
Immediate                         0, 1, 2 oder 4 Byte (4 nur 386+)

Format of Postbyte(Mod R/M aus Intel-Doku)
------------------------------------------
MM RRR MMM

MM  - Memory addressing mode
RRR - Register operand address
MMM - Memory operand address

RRR Register Names
Filds  8bit  16bit  32bit
000    AL     AX     EAX
001    CL     CX     ECX
010    DL     DX     EDX
011    Bl     BX     EBX
100    AH     SP     ESP
101    CH     BP     EBP
110    DH     SI     ESI
111    BH     DI     EDI

---

16bit memory (No 32 bit memory address prefix)
MMM   Default MM Field
Field Sreg     00        01          10             11=MMM is reg
000   DS       [BX+SI]   [BX+SI+o8]  [BX+SI+o16]
001   DS       [BX+DI]   [BX+DI+o8]  [BX+DI+o16]
010   SS       [BP+SI]   [BP+SI+o8]  [BP+SI+o16]
011   SS       [BP+DI]   [BP+DI+o8]  [BP+DI+o16]
100   DS       [SI]      [SI+o8]     [SI+o16]
101   DS       [DI]      [DI+o8]     [SI+o16]
110   SS       [o16]     [BP+o8]     [BP+o16]
111   DS       [BX]      [BX+o8]     [BX+o16]
Note: MMM=110,MM=0 Default Sreg is DS !!!!

32bit memory (Has 67h 32 bit memory address prefix)
MMM   Default MM Field
Field Sreg     00        01          10             11=MMM is reg
000   DS       [EAX]     [EAX+o8]    [EAX+o32]
001   DS       [ECX]     [ECX+o8]    [ECX+o32]
010   DS       [EDX]     [EDX+o8]    [EDX+o32]
011   DS       [EBX]     [EBX+o8]    [EBX+o32]
100   SIB      [SIB]     [SIB+o8]    [SIB+o32]
101   SS       [o32]     [EBP+o8]    [EBP+o32]
110   DS       [ESI]     [ESI+o8]    [ESI+o32]
111   DS       [EDI]     [EDI+o8]    [EDI+o32]
Note: MMM=110,MM=0 Default Sreg is DS !!!!

---

SIB is (Scale/Base/Index)
SS BBB III
Note: SIB address calculated as:
<sib address>=<Base>+<Index>*(2^(Scale))

Fild   Default Base
BBB    Sreg    Register   Note
000    DS      EAX
001    DS      ECX
010    DS      EDX
011    DS      EBX
100    SS      ESP
101    DS      o32        if MM=00 (Postbyte)
SS      EBP        if MM<>00 (Postbyte)
110    SS      ESI
111    DS      EDI

Fild  Index
III   register   Note
000   EAX
001   ECX
010   EDX
011   EBX
100              never Index SS can be 00
101   EBP
110   ESI
111   EDI

Fild Scale coefficient
SS   =2^(SS)
00   1
01   2
10   4
11   8
```